# Length of string is 0 on some iterations of for-loop and not others

Tags: c++, json, string, pointers, nlohmann-json

I'm using [nlohmann::json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) library for C++. I have the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <json.hpp>

using json = nlohmann::json;

int main(){
    json m;
    m["aaaaaaaa"] = 0;
    m["bbbbbbbbbbbbb"] = 0;
    m["ccccccccccccccccccc"] = 0;
    m["dddddddddddddddddd"] = 0;
    m["eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"] = 0;
    m["fffffffffffff"] = 0;
    m["gggggggggggg"] = 0;
    m["hhhhhhhhhhhh"] = 0;
    m["iiii"] = 0;
    m["jjjjjjjjjjjjjjj"] = 0;
    m["kkkkkkkkkkkkkk"] = 0;
    m["llllllllllllllll"] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        const char* mstr = m.dump().c_str();
        std::cout << strlen(mstr) << std::endl;
    }

}
```

I expect the output `strlen(mstr)` to be exactly the same for all 100 iterations of the for-loop.

On some runs, I get the expected output.

223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
Program ended with exit code: 0

But on other runs, I occasionally see that the string has length 0.

223
**0**
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
**0**
223
223
223
223
223
**0**
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
**0**
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
**0**
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223
Program ended with exit code: 0

How could this possibly be happening?

Comment: `m.dump().c_str()` is problematic, you're asking for a pointer from the guts of a temporary string.

Comment: @Mat thanks, why is this inherently dangerous?

Comment: Assuming `m.dump()` returns a `std::string`, that string object is a temporary. It will be destroyed at the end of the statement (at the `;`) unless you hold on to it explicitly (like in Gearoid's answer, or by binding it to a _const_ reference). Your code asks for `.c_str()` which returns a pointer owned by the temporary. Once the temporary is destroyed, that pointer is invalid (it will have been freed by the string's destructor).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`m.dump()` returns a temporary `string_t` object.  That temporary object goes out of scope when the `;` at the end of the whole `const char* mstr = m.dump().c_str();` expression is reached. That means the object is still alive when you call `c_str()` on it, but it is destroyed after you have saved the `char*` pointer to `mstr` but before you can print it to `std::cout`. The pointer is dangling at that point, so the behavior of the output is *undefined*.

You need to save the temporary object so you can keep the data alive until you are done using the pointer to it, eg:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    string_t mstr = m.dump();
    std::cout << strlen(mstr.c_str()) << std::endl;
}
```

Which can then be simplified since you don't actually need to use `strlen()` at all in this context, a C++ string knows its own length:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    string_t mstr = m.dump();
    std::cout << mstr.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Alternatively, you can print the `size()` while the temporary object is still in scope:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    std::cout << m.dump().size() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Regarding your last point, let's say I call a function `f(m.dump().c_str())` - I'm guessing this is still dangerous? I can't guarantee that `f` can access the pointer to the string? For some reason `f(m.dump().c_str())` actually works reliably

Comment: In `f(m.dump().c_str())`, the temp object returned by `dump()` is in scope the entire time `f()` is running, so it is perfectly safe for `f()` to use the pointer returned by `c_str()`.  What is not safe is for `f()` to save that pointer somewhere to be accessed later after `f()` has exited.

Comment: Thanks. What if the signature of `f` is `f(std::string& s)` ? Due to the constructor of `std::string` this is effectively reassigning the pointer returned by `c_str()` right?

Comment: In `f(m.dump().c_str())`, you can't pass the `const char*` to `f` if it is declared as `f(std::string&)`, the reference needs an actual `std::string` object. `f(m.dump())` would work, but only if `f` were declared as `f(std::string)` or `f(const std::string&)`, but not as `f(std::string&)` since a temp can't bind to a non-const reference.

Comment: In my compiler it worked, but to be specific the function signature has `const std::string&`

Comment: A `const char*` can be passed to a `const std::string&`, because `std::string` has a `const char*` constructor and the compiler can create a temp `std::string` and bind it to a `const std::string&` reference.  The same cannot be done with a non-const `std::string&`.

Comment: Thanks, but this won't suffer from the same deallocation issue as the original question?

Comment: No, it will not, for reasons I have already stated. You really need to read up on how the compiler is required to manage the lifetime of temporary objects.

Answer (score 5):

The dump function returns an object to the stack.By using a pointer from this object, you may occasionally find that the object memory gets reused before you can print the value. What should do is store the dumped string directly:

```
std::string mstr = m.dump();
std::cout << mstr.size() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks. This was my hunch, but I wasn't sure why the stack memory allocated to the temporary string would be "reused" or go out of scope if the function is still running? I know that the stack is clear when the function returns but during the execution of the function it should have access to all its stack variables right?

Comment: @user11909399 see the answer I just posted